# Site images not scaling?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, rackspace

I just migrated a WordPress site from my localhost to the Rackspace cloud hosting.  This is my first time working with Rackspace.  For some reason, the page-width on the new site is a little over 200px larger.  So all of the layout is thrown off, since it was styled for a page that was scaling smaller.  I'm looking for a way to either resolve this discrepancy, or at least fix the styling without having to re-size every rule that applied to width.  I am also using Bootstrap in the project.  I have tried various things to get the page to adapt to the new view, such as various settings for max-width, but nothing so far has had any affect.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey Ben, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is not specific enough to be answered here. Please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn more about the types of topics asked in this community.  It would help if you've posted some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap you can simply add

`class="img-responsive"`

to your  tags. this will allow your images to scale down. Now in order to get your images to scale up (larger) you'll want to add a css class like this.

```
.parent-class img {
    width:100%;
}
```

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/w74de/10/) Try resizing your browser window.